# App Icon for Apple watch app

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I noticed that the simulator for my apple watch app has a watch kit settings icon on the iPhone simulators home screen. when open that i see my watch kit app where I can toggle Show App on Apple Watch on and of. I see an icon for my watch app on the iPhone screen but I can not find the corresponding app icon in my Xcode project to populate this icon with my apps image.

I have added all the app icons for my watch kit app but this icon is still blank when running in the simulator.
Any ideas on *how/where I can find this app-Icon on Xcode?*

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, simulator needs to be cleaned. Click on **iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...**

[image]
To set up your iconset, you need to access to your WatchKit App target (see image below) and choose your App Icon Source.

[image]
And if you need help to export your app icon to the iOS resolutions, maybe you can download this app from AppleStore https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asset-generator-app-icon-set/id906380790?mt=12

Comment: Thanks for the help. For the app icon images for the apple watch, do you know if there is a launch screen image for the watch? I had it present when i first created my extension along with 3 icons that were designated something unassigned, incoildnt add any images to these and after some online research i saw that people were just deleting these images but i am not sure if the launch image is needed or not for app approval. After i delelted it, i cant seem to repopulate it back into my project.